# Hibernate: outer join on attribute value lists

Tags: hibernate, join, outer-join

I have an entity like:

```
public class CountEntry
{
  String company;
  String product;
  Date day;
  Integer stock;
}
```

Now I need a query that will return all possible combinations of a list of companies, products and dates, even if there is no entry on the table yet.

I cannot do an outer join as Company and Product are not database entities. And even if they were, I'd still need a solution to get a value for every day.

For example: if I query for:

> company in C1, C2
>   product in P1, P2
>   day between Feb 10 and Feb 11

and the table only contains

> C1, P1, Feb 10, stock=20
>   C1, P2, Feb 10, stock=5
>   C1, P2, Feb 11, stock=6
>   C2, P2, Feb 11, stock=1

I expect the query to return the full cartesian product of my criteria (we use projection lists and object arrays for fast processing):

> C1, P1, Feb 10, stock=20
>   C1, P1, Feb 11, stock=null
>   C1, P2, Feb 10, stock=5
>   C1, P2, Feb 11, stock=6
>   C2, P1, Feb 10, stock=null
>   C2, P1, Feb 11, stock=null
>   C2, P2, Feb 10, stock=null
>   C2, P2, Feb 11, stock=1

We choose this approach for performance issues, because the queries we do can return huge amounts of data, so we don't want a query returning entity objects (and we need object arrays later anyway). Our current post-processing relies on getting the cartesian product of the input query lists.

Is a select like this even possible in Hibernate? I have only found articles about outer joins with other entities. Can I create temporary virtual tables with my criteria lists and do an outer join on them? Or some other way?

Comment: I have found that I need row generator logic, and I will go for a solution that works like described here:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques

I will build a table with my cartesian product using row generators and then do an outer join to my CountEntry table. I will have to switch to native SQL for this but that is okay.

Answer (score 0):

So those things you want to aggregate are columns and not FK to other tables.
This is simple since you only need a group by query like this:

```
Object[] result = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select " +
    "   count(c), " +
    "   c.company, " +
    "   c.product, " +
    "   c.day " +
    "from CountEntry c " +
    "group by c.company, c.product, c.day", Object[].class )
.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: ok, that "count" field was misleading. This is not a row count but actually a field I want to display. Each line is to be read like "on Feb 10 we have 20 items of Product P1 from Company C1 in our store".